# Windows Phone xaml Listview hide last separator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

in my listview I have a usercontrol and a line separtor my listview is binded on my observable collection property my xaml is:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListaItinerari}" SelectedItem="{Binding ItinerarioSelezionato, Mode=TwoWay}" FontFamily="Global User Interface">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <UserControls:ItinerarioItemControl DataContext="{Binding}" />                                    
                                    <Line Margin="0,5,0,5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="{StaticResource LineThemeBrush}" X2="1"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

I would like hide last line separator.
I googled but I find nothing

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, but maybe it's better to put the seperator on top ( so above your usercontrol ).

And then do a binding on the visibility property of the seperator, using a converter. You pass along the item index and if the item index is 1 hide the seperator, otherwise show it.

To get the index of an item, look at an example here: http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/523/alternating-row-color-in-windows-store-listview

Comment: You don't understand my answer... By putting the separator on top there will no longer be a last! But there will be a first again. But that is easier to detect and to hide.

Comment: Yes I understand now.. its a good idea, however what he asked can also be achieved using attached properties..

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this using an attached property in WPF

[image]

```
 public class IndexItemHelper
{
    #region ListIndexer

    /// <summary>
    /// ListIndexer Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListIndexerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ListIndexer", typeof(List<ListItem>), typeof(IndexItemHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((List<ListItem>)null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnListIndexerChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ListIndexer property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static List<ListItem> GetListIndexer(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (List<ListItem>)d.GetValue(ListIndexerProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the ListIndexer property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetListIndexer(DependencyObject d, List<ListItem> value)
    {
        d.SetValue(ListIndexerProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles changes to the ListIndexer property.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnListIndexerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> oldListIndexer = (List<ListItem>)e.OldValue;
        List<ListItem> newListIndexer = (List<ListItem>)d.GetValue(ListIndexerProperty);
        UpdateDependencyObject(d);
    }

    #endregion


    #region ItemIndexOf

    /// <summary>
    /// ItemIndexOf Attached Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemIndexOfProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemIndexOf", typeof(object), typeof(IndexItemHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object)null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemIndexOfChanged)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the ItemIndexOf property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static object GetItemIndexOf(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (object)d.GetValue(ItemIndexOfProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the ItemIndexOf property. This dependency property 
    /// indicates ....
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetItemIndexOf(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        d.SetValue(ItemIndexOfProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles changes to the ItemIndexOf property.
    /// </summary>
    private static void OnItemIndexOfChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        object oldItemIndexOf = (object)e.OldValue;
        object newItemIndexOf = (object)d.GetValue(ItemIndexOfProperty);
        UpdateDependencyObject(d);
    }

    #endregion

    public static void UpdateDependencyObject(DependencyObject d)
    {
        var itemToGetIndexOf = GetItemIndexOf(d) as ListItem;
        var listToGetIndexFrom = GetListIndexer(d);
        if (itemToGetIndexOf == null || (listToGetIndexFrom == null || !listToGetIndexFrom.Any())) return;

        if (listToGetIndexFrom.IndexOf(itemToGetIndexOf) == (listToGetIndexFrom.Count - 1))
        {
            //this is the last line item
            var line = d as Line;
            if(line != null) line.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            var line = d as Line;
            if (line != null) line.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage of the attached properties:

```
<Grid x:Name="Main">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaItinerarie}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <Line Margin="0,5,0,5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red" X2="1" stackoverflow:IndexItemHelper.ItemIndexOf="{Binding }" stackoverflow:IndexItemHelper.ListIndexer="{Binding DataContext.ListaItinerarie, ElementName=Main}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Whenever the list or the item binding will change this will update...

Update: in windows phone instead of 'FrameworkPropertyMetadata' use 'PropertyMetadata'

Comment: sorry but the type FrameworkPropertyMetadata in Windows phone 8.1 xaml not found

Comment: use PropertyMetadata instead!